# Why python doesn't have Garbage Collector thread?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Java has daemon thread to monitor memory usage and do the gc task. From jstack I see

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f34b000e000 nid=0x808 waiting on condition [0x00007f34b6f02000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
....
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f34b0023000 nid=0x809 runnable 
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f34b0024800 nid=0x80a runnable 
"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f34b0026800 nid=0x80b runnable
```

But speaking of python, I wrote a

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gc
import time 
gc.enable()
while True:
    print "This prints once a minute."
    time.sleep(60)
```

I saw the the python process has only one thread,

```
$ cat /proc/1627/status
Name:   python
...
Threads:    1
```

The question is, why python doesn't have gc thread like Java? Then which thread does the gc task?

Comment: CPython works mostly by synchronous reference-counting, and runs in a single thread (unless the programmer explicitly creates more threads).  But this is a large topic, not well suited to this site's Q&A format.

Comment: @TimPeters. If the only one thread (main thread) is blocking waiting "sleep(60)", then the thread can't do other task like gc. That's what bothers me. I only need to know which thread does gc.

Comment: Why would you need to do gc if all the thread is doing is sleeping? There's literally nothing to collect.

Comment: @DanielRoseman. I removed most of the logic. "Sleep" is to make it easier to unserstand as a question. The background is, my machine has strict limit on thread number. I have a python daemon script. I need it to be always single-threaded. No unexpected many gc threads like java especially using ParallelGC.

Comment: Again, there is only one thread in CPython by default.  During the `sleep()`, Python does nothing whatsoever.  Forget about Java here.  CPython's garbage collection mechanisms have nothing in common with Java's.  A simple Google search will find you many articles on how CPython does do gc.  But if your _real_ concern is that you need your daemon to always be single-threaded, there's nothing you need to learn:  CPython _is_ single-threaded.  Don't create any threads of your own, and one thread is all there will ever be.

Comment: @TimPeters. Thanks, it really helps. I'll close the post.

Answer (score 2):

If you start java with `-XX:+UseSerialGC` options you will not see any GC thread.
For single threaded GC algorithm application thread can be used to do GC activities.

Dedicated threads required for

- Parallel GC (you need more than single thread)
- Concurrent GC (GC activities running in parallel with application logic)